# How to provision a VM on Azure using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a snippet of PowerShell code (shown below) which pipelines commands together in order to create a new VM using existing disks. The problem I have is that the code is a general purpose function and I do not know how many data disks need to be added to the VM which makes it difficult to pipeline these together.

I have tried using -inputobject but this does not seem to work with the New-AzureVM command, any ideas appreciated as I need the data disks attached before the VM is started.

Thanks, Richard

```
function Build_Existing_VM($serviceName, $osDisk, $dataDisks, $availabilitySetName, $subnetName)
{
   $vmConfig = New-AzureVMConfig -Name $serviceName `
                   -InstanceSize Medium `
                   -DiskName $osDisk `
                   -AvailabilitySetName $availabilitySetName `
                   -HostCaching "ReadOnly" |
                   Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "rdp" -PublicPort 63000 -LocalPort 3389 -Protocol tcp |
                   Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "web" -PublicPort 80    -LocalPort 6080 -Protocol tcp |
                   Set-AzureSubnet $subnetName
   $i = 0
   foreach ($dd in $dataDisks.Split(','))
   {
      $vmConfig = (Add-AzureDataDisk -Import -LUN $i -DiskName $dd -inputobject $vmConfig)
      $i++
  }
   New-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -VNetName $virtualNetworkName -inputobject $vmConfig
```

}

Comment: Not sure about -inputobject, but... you'll want to parameterize the public RDP port number if you're going to have multiple Virtual Machines within the same service name. You've already set it up to create a non-load-balanced endpoint, which is good. You'll probably want to add -LBSetName to your "Web" endpoint; otherwise that will be port-forwarded as well.

Comment: David, Thanks for the comments. Currently the services only have one VM, but once I sort out the issue of how to add the data disks I will look at sorting out the load balancing issues. Just not sure at the moment how to use PowerShell pipelines to add a variable number of data disks.